# Linux interface name changes from eno0 to eno0s1 after kernel upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, network-interface

On Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel v5.16, the network interface is named `eno1`. However, after upgrading to kernel v6.7, the interface name became `eno1s0`.

Why did this change happen? Can I force the kernel to use the old name `eno0` without adding that `s0` to the end?

Comment: you can make over udev (oldschool) or over https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.link.5.html